# finding air gap shear stress in a permanent magnet generator

Tags: torque, electrical, rpm

I have found that the air gap shear stress is a limiting factor when sizing a generator, but how do I find the value for it?

Comment: From the torque, most likely.

Comment: From the difference in speed of the two surfaces.